# DataJpaTest: Numeric scale default seems to be 0 with spring-boot-starter 2.7.1

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I have a DataJpaTest with some `schema.sql` and `data.sql` for preparing the postgresql in-memory database. I've just upgraded `spring-boot-starter-parent` from 2.6.3 to 2.7.1, and now the test fails.

schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table(
    id BIGSERIAL,
    name TEXT,
    problematic_number NUMERIC NOT NULL
);
```

data:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (name, problematic_number) VALUES ('something', 1.4321);
```

For some reason a test is failing now with:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :1.4321
Actual   :1
```

I also connected to the h2 database and I got really "1" in here instead of "1.4321". Before my spring upgrade, the test was fine.

Did the default scale for numeric maybe change? if I change my `schema.sql` to `NUMERIC(10,4)`, the test succeeds.